# Find a set A & a set B such that $A \cap (A \times B) \neq \emptyset$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find a set $A$ and a set $B$ such that $A \cap (A \times B) \neq \emptyset$.

For my solution I came up with the sets $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B = \{1,2\}$.

Is this a correct answer?

Comment: $A \times B = \{ (1,1), \ (1,2), \ (2,1), \ (2,2)\}$

Comment: Well... Given the solution you came up with, what is the value of $A \cap (A \times B)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for your choices $A×B = \{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2)\}$ which is disjoint to $A$.

The condition can be rewritten as $∃a ∈ A, b ∈ B, a'∈A: a' = (a, b)$. So you can take $B = \{1\}$ and $A = \{1, (1, 1)\}$. Then $A ∩ (A × B) = \{(1, 1)\}$.

Comment: I think that $A \times B$ is in fact **not** disjoint from $A$.

Comment: @barakmanos: $A$ only contains two elements, $1$ and $2$, which are both not contained in $A × B$.

Comment: Oh yep, my mistake...

Answer (score 1):

Take
$$
A = \{\diamond,(\diamond,\heartsuit)\}\qquad\text{and}\qquad B = \{\heartsuit\}.$$